# Android 12 public directory storage access issue while saving image

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

Issue:
While allowing simple storage read and write permission it is sometime working fine and able to save image on my public directory but sometime not working after uninstalling and reinstalling and allowing [permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvSRh.png) but it is giving "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: share the code of your `manifest` file. and error log too.

Comment: share the code and write which android version you are targeting